# how to debug System.ServiceModel.FaultException in WCF?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, wcf

I am new to this I can't seem to get meaningful (to me) debugging information. Is there a "best" or even "good" method to trace the error to this?

I have a client WPF application on my laptop that addresses a separate server running WCF hosted in IIS 7. The services on the server were added to the client project with "Add Service Reference". The service was then configured to provide asynchronous methods and updated on in the client.

When run, I keep getting:

> System.ServiceModel.FaultException: The server was unable to process the request to an internal error. For more inforamtion about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults  configuration behavior) on the server in order to sent the exception infomration back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Frameowrk SDK documentation and inspect the .server trace logs.

I have been unable to trace this or keep missing the solution. (and really don't even know where the error is coming from).

Any ideas?

Here is the client `app.config` file (where I think the error is -- but I could be very wrong!):

```
<system.serviceModel>
   <bindings>
     <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_INovaDataService" />
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_INovaDataService1" />
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_INovaDataService2" />
     </basicHttpBinding>
   </bindings>
   <client>
      <endpoint name="MyLocalService" 
          address="http://localhost/NovaWebSite/Nova.svc" 
          binding="basicHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_INovaDataService" 
          contract="DataService.INovaDataService" />
      <endpoint name="LibraryService" 
          address="http://192.168.1.100:43175/NovaWebSite/Nova.svc"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" 
          bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_INovaDataService1"
          contract="DataService.INovaDataService" />
      <endpoint name="OfficeService" 
          address="http://10.0.11.100:43175/NovaWebSite/Nova.svc"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" 
          bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_INovaDataService2"
          contract="OfficeService.INovaDataService" />
   </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I'm thinking there is probably a good/simple way to use the single

```
 contract="DataService.INovaDataService"
```

but change the address endpoint in code (I know the `DataService.INovaDataService` contract does work correctly).

Any suggestions would sure be appreciated.

Comment: Based on the message in the exception, the issue is on the server and has nothing to do with your client.  Enable WCF tracing on the box hosting the WCF service, and also check the event viewer (and any other logs the service may be generating).

Comment: @Tim Thanks. So the client is ok. Could you give me a hint how to get WCF tracing on the server?

Comment: [Configuring Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a good place to start.  Google WCF Tracing and there's lots of links and how tos.